# Fastest algorithm for circle shift N sized array for M position

Tags: algorithm, arrays, math, puzzle, programming-pearls

What is the fastest algorithm for circle shifting array for M positions? 
For example, `[3 4 5 2 3 1 4]` shift M = 2 positions should be `[1 4 3 4 5 2 3]`.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

If you want O(n) time and no extra memory usage (since array was specified), use the algorithm from Jon Bentley's book, "Programming Pearls 2nd Edition".  It swaps all the elements twice.  Not as fast as using linked lists but uses less memory and is conceptually simple.

```
shiftArray( theArray, M ):
    size = len( theArray )
    assert( size > M )
    reverseArray( theArray, 0, size - 1 )
    reverseArray( theArray, 0, M - 1 )
    reverseArray( theArray, M, size - 1 )
```

reverseArray( anArray, startIndex, endIndex ) reverses the order of elements from startIndex to endIndex, inclusive.

Comment: I wonder when would you actually need to do physical array shifting.

Comment: @Vinko: Perhaps as a part of larger task of computing several cycle-shifts applied to different overlapping parts of an array.

Comment: I'd replace `assert(size>M)` with `M = M % size` and check for `M==0`. That would make the function more flexible.

Comment: In terms of number of swaps, this algorithm is not optimal.

Comment: @Vinko i use this algorithm. We have small arrays that have about 100 elements, and perform lots of operations on them. It has to be an array because we need random access for most operations. Creating a linked list would be much slower than just the in-place swap. So for us its an performance issue. Allocating memory is expensive.

Answer (score 28):

## Optimal solution

Question asked for fastest. Reversing three times is simplest but moves every element exactly twice, takes O(N) time and O(1) space. It is possible to circle shift an array moving each element exactly once also in O(N) time and O(1) space.

### Idea

We can circle shift an array of length `N=9` by `M=1` with one cycle:

```
tmp = arr[0]; arr[0] = arr[1]; ... arr[7] = arr[8]; arr[8] = tmp;
```

And if `N=9`, `M=3` we can circle shift with three cycles:

1. `tmp = arr[0]; arr[0] = arr[3]; arr[3] = tmp;`
2. `tmp = arr[1]; arr[1] = arr[4]; arr[4] = tmp;`
3. `tmp = arr[2]; arr[2] = arr[5]; arr[5] = tmp;`

Note each element is read once and written once.

### Diagram of shifting `N=9, M=3`

[image: Diagram of cycle shift]

The first cycle is show in black with numbers indicating the order of operations. The second and third cycles are shown in grey.

The number of cycles required is the [Greatest Common Divisor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor) (GCD) of `N` and `M`. If the GCD is 3, we start a cycle at each of `{0,1,2}`. Calculating the GCD is fast with the [binary GCD algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_GCD_algorithm).

Example code:

```
// n is length(arr)
// shift is how many place to cycle shift left
void cycle_shift_left(int arr[], int n, int shift) {
  int i, j, k, tmp;
  if(n <= 1 || shift == 0) return;
  shift = shift % n; // make sure shift isn't >n
  int gcd = calc_GCD(n, shift);

  for(i = 0; i < gcd; i++) {
    // start cycle at i
    tmp = arr[i];
    for(j = i; 1; j = k) {
      k = j+shift;
      if(k >= n) k -= n; // wrap around if we go outside array
      if(k == i) break; // end of cycle
      arr[j] = arr[k];
    }
    arr[j] = tmp;
  }
}
```

### Code in C for any array type:

```
// circle shift an array left (towards index zero)
// - ptr    array to shift
// - n      number of elements
// - es     size of elements in bytes
// - shift  number of places to shift left
void array_cycle_left(void *_ptr, size_t n, size_t es, size_t shift)
{
  char *ptr = (char*)_ptr;
  if(n <= 1 || !shift) return; // cannot mod by zero
  shift = shift % n; // shift cannot be greater than n

  // Using GCD
  size_t i, j, k, gcd = calc_GCD(n, shift);
  char tmp[es];

  // i is initial starting position
  // Copy from k -> j, stop if k == i, since arr[i] already overwritten
  for(i = 0; i < gcd; i++) {
    memcpy(tmp, ptr+es*i, es); // tmp = arr[i]
    for(j = i; 1; j = k) {
      k = j+shift;
      if(k >= n) k -= n;
      if(k == i) break;
      memcpy(ptr+es*j, ptr+es*k, es); // arr[j] = arr[k];
    }
    memcpy(ptr+es*j, tmp, es); // arr[j] = tmp;
  }
}

// cycle right shifts away from zero
void array_cycle_right(void *_ptr, size_t n, size_t es, size_t shift)
{
  if(!n || !shift) return; // cannot mod by zero
  shift = shift % n; // shift cannot be greater than n
  // cycle right by `s` is equivalent to cycle left by `n - s`
  array_cycle_left(_ptr, n, es, n - shift);
}

// Get Greatest Common Divisor using binary GCD algorithm
// http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_GCD_algorithm
unsigned int calc_GCD(unsigned int a, unsigned int b)
{
  unsigned int shift, tmp;

  if(a == 0) return b;
  if(b == 0) return a;

  // Find power of two divisor
  for(shift = 0; ((a | b) & 1) == 0; shift++) { a >>= 1; b >>= 1; }

  // Remove remaining factors of two from a - they are not common
  while((a & 1) == 0) a >>= 1;

  do
  {
    // Remove remaining factors of two from b - they are not common
    while((b & 1) == 0) b >>= 1;

    if(a > b) { tmp = a; a = b; b = tmp; } // swap a,b
    b = b - a;
  }
  while(b != 0);

  return a << shift;
}
```

*Edit*: This algorithm may also have better performance vs array reversal (when `N` is large and `M` is small) due to cache locality, since we are looping over the array in small steps.

*Final note:* if your array is small, triple reverse is simple. If you have a large array, it is worth the overhead of working out the GCD to reduce the number of moves by a factor of 2.
Ref: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/array-rotation/

Comment: (Have a look at [Han's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26773023/3789665) how to handle this implicitly.)

Comment: This code is much simpler and easier to understand than "Han's answer". The C code is not, though. Just stick to the "example code" at the top of the answer. Computing the GCD is a recursive one-liner: `size_t gcd(size_t a, size_t b) {return b == 0 ? a : gcd(b, a % b);}`.

Comment: This code is also 10 times faster for a shift of 1, and at least 3 times faster for other random shifts, in a quick test I just did. It does less copying.

Comment: See also [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11893053/circular-left-shift-of-an-array-by-n-positions-in-java/18154984#18154984) for further intuition and justification for this solution.

Comment: I think the gcd can be calculated implicitly as the smallest non-zero index reached on the first loop. This might be what greybeard is referring to.

Answer (score 24):

It's just a matter of representation. Keep the current index as an integer variable and when traversing the array use modulo operator to know when to wrap around. Shifting is then only changing the value of the current index, wrapping it around the size of the array. This is of course O(1).

For example:

```
int index = 0;
Array a = new Array[SIZE];

get_next_element() {
    index = (index + 1) % SIZE; 
    return a[index];
}

shift(int how_many) {
    index = (index+how_many) % SIZE;
}
```

Comment: This could be written a little clearer. Perhaps something like "instead of updating the array, update an integer storing the current start of the array". Also, this approach turns an O(1) operation -- push/pop -- into an O(n) operation, so there are obvious tradeoffs.

Comment: This is a wonderful "real world" solution, that i hope everybody would reach for. Though, i think the implication of this question is that it's a programming interview and you are expected to mutate the array in place.

Answer (score 8):

Set it up with pointers, and it takes almost no time.  Each element points to the next, and the "last" (there is no last; after all, you said it was circular) points to the first.  One pointer to the "start" (first element), and maybe a length, and you have your array.  Now, to do your shift, you just walk your start pointer along the circle.

Ask for a good algorithm, and you get sensible ideas.  Ask for *fastest*, and you get weird ideas!

Comment: But wouldn't you end up in checking for end each time while traversing the list?

Comment: yeah, but that's fast. Or you can use modulo (or bitwise AND if list is a power of 2).

Comment: You would check for end anyway, even with a conventional array.  But if you keep a length, it's as simple as writing a loop or decrementing a count to zero.

Comment: The question asks for arrays not linked lists.

Answer (score 4):

This algorithm runs in O(n) time and O(1) space. 
The idea is to trace each cyclic group in the shift (numbered by `nextGroup` variable).

```
var shiftLeft = function(list, m) {
    var from = 0;
    var val = list[from];
    var nextGroup = 1;
    for(var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        var to = ((from - m) + list.length) % list.length;
        if(to == from)
            break;

        var temp = list[to];
        list[to] = val;
        from = to;
        val = temp;

        if(from < nextGroup) {
            from = nextGroup++;
            val = list[from];
        }
    }
    return list;
}
```

Comment: Nice algorithm. But there is too much copying happening: `list[] -> val`, `list[] -> tmp`, `val -> list[]`, `tmp -> val`. If you reverse the order of moving things around, you can copy the first element of a cycle to `val`, then copy the next element forward (`list[] -> list[]` directly), repeatedly, until you get to the last element, where you write `val`. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32698823/7328782

Answer (score 3):

```
def shift(nelements, k):       
    result = []
    length = len(nelements)
    start = (length - k) % length
    for i in range(length):
        result.append(nelements[(start + i) % length])
    return result
```

This code works well even on negative shift k

Answer (score 3):

**Here is a simple and efficient general in place rotate function in C++, less than 10 lines.**

which is excerpted from my answer on another question. [How to rotate an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42714433/3625404)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

// same logic with STL implementation, but simpler, since no return value needed.
template <typename Iterator>
void rotate_by_gcd_like_swap(Iterator first, Iterator mid, Iterator last) {
    if (first == mid) return;
    Iterator old = mid;
    for (; mid != last;) {
        std::iter_swap(first, mid);
        ++first, ++mid;
        if (first == old) old = mid; // left half exhausted
        else if (mid == last) mid = old;
    }
}

int main() {
    using std::cout;
    std::vector<int> v {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
    cout << "before rotate: ";
    for (auto x: v) cout << x << ' '; cout << '\n';
    int k = 7;
    rotate_by_gcd_like_swap(v.begin(), v.begin() + k, v.end());
    cout << " after rotate: ";
    for (auto x: v) cout << x << ' '; cout << '\n';
    cout << "sz = " << v.size() << ", k = " << k << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 3):

A very simple solution. This is a very fast way, here I use a temp array with the same size or original and attach to the original variable at the end. 
This method use O(n) temporal complexity and O(n) space complexity and it is very simple to implement.

```
int[] a  = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
    int k = 2;
    int[] queries = {2,3};

    int[] temp = new int[a.length];
    for (int i = 0; i<a.length; i++)
        temp[(i+k)%a.length] = a[i];

    a = temp;
```

Comment: temp array is O(n) space not O(1)

Comment: Thanks for suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

C arrayShiftRight function. If shift is negative the function shifts array left.
It is optimized for less memory usage. Running time is O(n).

```
void arrayShiftRight(int array[], int size, int shift) {
    int len;

    //cut extra shift
    shift %= size;

    //if shift is less then 0 - redirect shifting left
    if ( shift < 0 ) {
        shift += size;
    }

    len = size - shift;

    //choosing the algorithm which needs less memory
    if ( shift < len ) {
        //creating temporary array
        int tmpArray[shift];

        //filling tmp array
        for ( int i = 0, j = len; i < shift; i++, j++ ) {
            tmpArray[i] = array[j];
        }

        //shifting array
        for ( int i = size - 1, j = i - shift; j >= 0; i--, j-- ) {
            array[i] = array[j];
        }

        //inserting lost values from tmp array
        for ( int i = 0; i < shift; i++ ) {
            array[i] = tmpArray[i];
        }
    } else {
        //creating temporary array
        int tmpArray[len];

        //filling tmp array
        for ( int i = 0; i < len; i++ ) {
            tmpArray[i] = array[i];
        }

        //shifting array
        for ( int i = 0, j = len; j < size; i++, j++ ) {
            array[i] = array[j];
        }

        //inserting lost values from tmp array
        for ( int i = shift, j = 0; i < size; i++, j++ ) {
            array[i] = tmpArray[j];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the data structure you use, you can do it in O(1). I think the fastest way is to hold the array in the form of a linked list, and have a hash table that can translate between "index" in the array to "pointer" to the entry. This way you can find the relevant heads and tails in O(1), and do the reconnection in O(1) (and update the hash table after the switch in O(1)). This of course would be a very "messy" solution, but if all you're interested in is the speed of the shift, that will do (on the expense of longer insertion and lookup in the array, but it will still remain O(1))

If you have the data in a pure array, I don't think you can avoid O(n).

Coding-wise, it depends on what language you are using.

In Python for example, you could "slice" it (assume n is the shift size):

```
result = original[-n:]+original[:-n]
```

(I know that hash lookup is in theory not O(1) but we're practical here and not theoretical, at least I hope so...)

Answer (score 1):

This should work to shift an arry circularly:
Input : { 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8 };
Output value present in array after the forloops : {8,7,1,2,3,5,6,8,7}

```
 class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] array = { 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8 };
            int index = 2;
            int[] tempArray = new int[array.Length];
            array.CopyTo(tempArray, 0);

            for (int i = 0; i < array.Length - index; i++)
            {
                array[index + i] = tempArray[i];
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < index; i++)
            {
                array[i] = tempArray[array.Length -1 - i];
            }            
        }
    }
```

Comment: @JerryPenner solution doesn't use O(n) additional memory

Answer (score 1):

In theory, the fastest one is a loop like this:

```
if (begin != middle && middle != end)
{
    for (i = middle; ; )
    {
        swap(arr[begin++], arr[i++]);
        if (begin == middle && i == end) { break; }
        if (begin == middle) { middle = i; }
        else if (i == end) { i = middle; }
    }
}
```

In practice, you should profile it and see.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the c++ implementation. Time Complexity O(n), Space Complexity O(1)

```
M = M % theArray.size();
reverse(theArray.begin(), theArray.end());
reverse(nums.begin(), theArray.begin()+ M);
reverse(theArray.begin()+ M, theArray.end());
```

Here is another implementation using Cyclic Replacements technique. Time Complexity O(n), Space Complexity O(1).

```
void rotate(vector<int>& nums, int k) {
    int n = nums.size();
    int start = 0;
    int count = 0;
    while(count < n) {
        int temp = nums[start];
        int i = (start + k) % n;
        while(i != start) {
            int temp2 = nums[i];
            nums[i] = temp;
            temp = temp2;
            i = (i + k) % n;
            count++;
        }
        nums[i] = temp;
        count++;
        start++;
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep two indexes to the array, one index starts from beginning of the array to the end of array. Another index starts from the Mth position from last and loops through the last M elements any number of times. Takes O(n) at all times. No extra space required.

```
circleArray(Elements,M){
 int size=size-of(Elements);

 //first index
 int i1=0;

 assert(size>M)

 //second index starting from mth position from the last
 int i2=size-M;

 //until first index reaches the end
 while(i1<size-1){

  //swap the elements of the array pointed by both indexes
  swap(i1,i2,Elements);

  //increment first pointer by 1
  i1++;

  //increment second pointer. if it goes out of array, come back to
  //mth position from the last
  if(++i2==size) i2=size-M;

 }
}
```

Comment: There is bug in your implementation! See my post above!

Answer (score 0):

`circleArray` has some errors and is not working in all cases!

The loop must continue `while i1 < i2` NOT `i1 < last - 1`.

```
void Shift(int* _array, int _size, int _moves)
{
    _moves = _size - _moves;
    int i2 = _moves;
         int i1 = -1;
         while(++i1 < i2)
    {
        int tmp = _array[i2];
        _array[i2] = _array[i1];
        _array[i1] = tmp;
        if(++i2 == _size) i2 = _moves;
    }
}
```

Comment: this code only works on specific cases, so it's no good. for example, if you have `5, 9, 4, 0, 11` and you shift it by 3, it will give you `4, 0, 11, 9, 5` instead of `4, 0, 11, 5, 9`.

Answer (score 0):

```java
static int [] shift(int arr[], int index, int k, int rem)
{
    if(k <= 0 || arr == null || arr.length == 0 || rem == 0 || index >= arr.length)
    {
        return arr;
    }

    int temp = arr[index];

    arr = shift(arr, (index+k) % arr.length, k, rem - 1);

    arr[(index+k) % arr.length] = temp;

    return arr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See this if you are interested in a Java implementation:

[Programming Pearls: Circular Left/Right Shift Operation](http://programmingpearls.blogspot.com/search?updated-min=2011-01-01T00%3A00%3A00-08%3A00&updated-max=2012-01-01T00%3A00%3A00-08%3A00&max-results=2)

Answer (score 0):

Ruby example:

```
def move_cyclic2 array, move_cnt
  move_cnt = array.length - move_cnt % array.length 
  if !(move_cnt == 0 || move_cnt == array.length)            
    array.replace( array[move_cnt..-1] + array[0...move_cnt] )  
  end   
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a nother one (C++):

```
void shift_vec(vector<int>& v, size_t a)
{
    size_t max_s = v.size() / a;
    for( size_t s = 1; s < max_s; ++s )
        for( size_t i = 0; i < a; ++i )
            swap( v[i], v[s*a+i] );
    for( size_t i = 0; i < a; ++i )
        swap( v[i], v[(max_s*a+i) % v.size()] );
}
```

Of course it is not nearly as elegant as the famous reverse-three-times solution, but depending on the machine it can be [similary fast](http://ideone.com/St7wPv).

Answer (score 0):

A friend of mine while joking asked me how to shift an array, I came up with this solutions (see ideone link), now I've seen yours, someone seems a bit esoteric.

Take a look [here](https://ideone.com/6avuUF).

```
#include <iostream>

#include <assert.h>

#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

struct VeryElaboratedDataType
{
    int a;
    int b;
};

namespace amsoft
{
    namespace inutils
    {
        enum EShiftDirection
        {
            Left,
            Right
        };
template 
<typename T,size_t len>
void infernalShift(T infernalArray[],int positions,EShiftDirection direction = EShiftDirection::Right)
{
    //assert the dudes
    assert(len > 0 && "what dude?");
    assert(positions >= 0 && "what dude?");

    if(positions > 0)
    {
    ++positions;
    //let's make it fit the range
    positions %= len;

    //if y want to live as a forcio, i'l get y change direction by force
    if(!direction)
    {
        positions = len - positions;
    }

    // here I prepare a fine block of raw memory... allocate once per thread
    static unsigned char WORK_BUFFER[len * sizeof(T)];
    // std::memset (WORK_BUFFER,0,len * sizeof(T));
    // clean or not clean?, well
    // Hamlet is a prince, a prince does not clean

    //copy the first chunk of data to the 0 position
    std::memcpy(WORK_BUFFER,reinterpret_cast<unsigned char *>(infernalArray) + (positions)*sizeof(T),(len - positions)*sizeof(T));
    //copy the second chunk of data to the len - positions position
    std::memcpy(WORK_BUFFER+(len - positions)*sizeof(T),reinterpret_cast<unsigned char *>(infernalArray),positions * sizeof(T));

    //now bulk copy back to original one
    std::memcpy(reinterpret_cast<unsigned char *>(infernalArray),WORK_BUFFER,len * sizeof(T));

    }

}
template 
<typename T>
void printArray(T infernalArrayPrintable[],int len)
{
        for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
    {
        std::cout << infernalArrayPrintable[i] << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

}
template 
<>
void printArray(VeryElaboratedDataType infernalArrayPrintable[],int len)
{
        for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
    {
        std::cout << infernalArrayPrintable[i].a << "," << infernalArrayPrintable[i].b << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

}
}
}




int main() {
    // your code goes here
    int myInfernalArray[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};

    VeryElaboratedDataType myInfernalArrayV[] = {{1,1},{2,2},{3,3},{4,4},{5,5},{6,6},{7,7},{8,8},{9,9}};
    amsoft::inutils::printArray(myInfernalArray,sizeof(myInfernalArray)/sizeof(int));
    amsoft::inutils::infernalShift<int,sizeof(myInfernalArray)/sizeof(int)>(myInfernalArray,4);
    amsoft::inutils::printArray(myInfernalArray,sizeof(myInfernalArray)/sizeof(int));
    amsoft::inutils::infernalShift<int,sizeof(myInfernalArray)/sizeof(int)>(myInfernalArray,4,amsoft::inutils::EShiftDirection::Left);
    amsoft::inutils::printArray(myInfernalArray,sizeof(myInfernalArray)/sizeof(int));
    amsoft::inutils::infernalShift<int,sizeof(myInfernalArray)/sizeof(int)>(myInfernalArray,10);
    amsoft::inutils::printArray(myInfernalArray,sizeof(myInfernalArray)/sizeof(int));


    amsoft::inutils::printArray(myInfernalArrayV,sizeof(myInfernalArrayV)/sizeof(VeryElaboratedDataType));
    amsoft::inutils::infernalShift<VeryElaboratedDataType,sizeof(myInfernalArrayV)/sizeof(VeryElaboratedDataType)>(myInfernalArrayV,4);
    amsoft::inutils::printArray(myInfernalArrayV,sizeof(myInfernalArrayV)/sizeof(VeryElaboratedDataType));
    amsoft::inutils::infernalShift<VeryElaboratedDataType,sizeof(myInfernalArrayV)/sizeof(VeryElaboratedDataType)>(myInfernalArrayV,4,amsoft::inutils::EShiftDirection::Left);
    amsoft::inutils::printArray(myInfernalArrayV,sizeof(myInfernalArrayV)/sizeof(VeryElaboratedDataType));
    amsoft::inutils::infernalShift<VeryElaboratedDataType,sizeof(myInfernalArrayV)/sizeof(VeryElaboratedDataType)>(myInfernalArrayV,10);
    amsoft::inutils::printArray(myInfernalArrayV,sizeof(myInfernalArrayV)/sizeof(VeryElaboratedDataType));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: (Even designing something `infernal`, consider how to talk to an angel. May I recommend a spelling checker for text communication involving computers?)

Comment: If you type text going public into your web browser more frequently than once a year, use a plug in or add on with your favourite browser. Wary of _internet exploder_ or the toxic heavy metal one, I use firefox more often than not - it offers flavours of English from New Zealand to Canada and back. (I failed to come up with a checker using a blacklist of words/phrases to avoid.)

Comment: thanks for the advice dude. IExploder? only sometimes, no good for my health. i'll try grammarly (just to add some personal data to the big global market) with chrome. if y make a blacklist would be helpfull. it's time depending?  if i don't sleep for many hours i really can't tell what i can write

Answer (score 0):

This method will do this work :

```
public static int[] solution1(int[] A, int K) {
    int temp[] = new int[A.length];

    int count = 0;

    int orignalItration = (K < A.length) ? K :(K%A.length); 


    for (int i = orignalItration; i < A.length; i++) {
        temp[i] = A[count++];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < orignalItration; i++) {
        temp[i] = A[count++];
    }

    return temp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @IsaacTurner and not that elegant due to unnecessary copying, but implementation is quite short.

The idea - swap element A on index 0 with the element B which sits on destination of A. Now B is first. Swap it with the element C which sits on destination of B. Continue until the destination is not at 0.

If the greatest common divisor is not 1 then you're not finished yet - you need to continue swapping, but now using index 1 at your starting and end point.

Continue until your starting position is not the gcd.

```
int gcd(int a, int b) => b == 0 ? a : gcd(b, a % b);

public int[] solution(int[] A, int K)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < gcd(A.Length, K); i++)
    {
        for (var j = i; j < A.Length - 1; j++)
        {
            var destIndex = ((j-i) * K + K + i) % A.Length;
            if (destIndex == i) break;
            var destValue = A[destIndex];
            A[destIndex] = A[i];
            A[i] = destValue;
        }
    }

    return A;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution in Java which got me 100% Task Score and 100% Correctness at Codility:

```
class Solution {
    public int[] solution(int[] A, int K) {
        // write your code in Java SE 8
        if (A.length > 0)
        {
            int[] arr = new int[A.length];
            if (K > A.length)
                K = K % A.length;

            for (int i=0; i<A.length-K; i++)
                arr[i+K] = A[i];

            for (int j=A.length-K; j<A.length; j++)
                arr[j-(A.length-K)] = A[j];

            return arr;
        }
        else
            return new int[0];
    }
}
```

Note that despite seeing two `for` loops, the iteration on the entire array is only done once.

Answer (score 0):

Swift 4 version for shifting array left.

```swift
func rotLeft(a: [Int], d: Int) -> [Int] {

   var result = a
   func reverse(start: Int, end: Int) {
      var start = start
      var end = end
      while start < end {
         result.swapAt(start, end)
         start += 1
         end -= 1
      }
   }

   let lenght = a.count
   reverse(start: 0, end: lenght - 1)
   reverse(start: lenght - d, end: lenght - 1)
   reverse(start: 0, end: lenght - d - 1)
   return result
}
```

For example, if input array is `a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`, and left shift offset is `d = 4`, then result will be `[5, 1, 2, 3, 4]`

Answer (score 0):

@IsaacTurner 's answer (C)
https://stackoverflow.com/a/32698823/4386969

and @SomeStrangeUser 's answer (Java):
https://stackoverflow.com/a/18154984/4386969

provide a simple O(N) time, O(1) space algorithm that answers the question and requires exactly N element assignments. I believe though (and someone correct me if I'm wrong) that computing the gcd between N and M is not necessary; simply counting the number of elements that we have put in their correct place should suffice. This is because once we have put an element in its correct place, we are guaranteed that we won't have to access it again neither in the current cycle nor in subsequent ones.

Here is a Python 3 implementation with this additional simplification:

```
# circle shift an array to the left by M 
def arrayCircleLeftShift(a, M):
    N = len(a)
    numAccessed = 0
    cycleIdx = 0
    while numAccessed != N:
        idx = cycleIdx
        swapIdx = (idx + M) % N
        tmp = a[idx]
        while swapIdx != cycleIdx:
            a[idx] = a[swapIdx]
            numAccessed += 1
            idx = swapIdx
            swapIdx = (idx + M) % N
        a[idx] = tmp
        numAccessed += 1
        cycleIdx += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it is an old post, however here is an optimal solution in O(n): each element is moved exactly once and no extra space is needed. It is very similar to the solution proposed by Isaac Turner but no requires gcd computation.

```
public static void shiftArray(int[] A, int k) {
    if (A.length == 0) {
        return;
    }
    k = k % A.length;
    k = (k + A.length) % A.length; // ensure k is positive
    if (k == 0) {
        return;
    }
    int i = 0, i0 = 0;
    int x = A[0];
    for (int u = 0; u < A.length; u++) { // count number of shifted elements
        int j = (i - k + A.length) % A.length; // ensure modulo is positive
        if (j == i0) { // end of a (sub-)cycle, advance to next one
            A[i] = x;
            x = A[i = ++i0];
        } else {
            A[i] = A[j];
            i = j;
        }
    }
}
```