# Algorithm to rotate an array in linear time

Tags: arrays, algorithm

How to rotate an integer array by `i` times using `swap` function only in linear time.

Comment: Please elaborate your question a bit.  What dimension has the array?  What do you mean by "rotating an array"?  Give an example input and output.  Consider using punctuation and capital letters where appropriate.

Comment: What have you tried?  How does it not work?  IOW, you need to try first before we help (we're not going to write it form you)

Comment: @sven suppose input array is {1,2,3,4,5} output array after one right rotation is {5,1,2,3,4}.

Comment: @kevin for rotating it i times we can do it in o(n^2) times but i want o(n) complexity.

Comment: don't know why someone down voted my answer, but it's possible with a easy small algorithm in O(n)! See my answer for details.

Comment: You should state that the operation should be done `in place` or O(1) space, otherwise, we just use another block of memory, do 3 `memmove`s.

Comment: @SvenMarnach The dimension of the array is irrelevant. What is wanted here is an algorithm, or a method, or a function, but any of those will work with any value of *N*.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/876293/fastest-algorithm-for-circle-shift-n-sized-array-for-m-position

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You can do this in linear time by using a reverse() helper.

```
// rotate array of size=size, by n positions
void rotate(int array[], int size, int n)
{
  // reverse array[0...size-1]
  reverse(array, 0, size-1);

  // reverse A[0...n-1]
  reverse(array, 0, n-1);

  // reverse A[n...size-1]
  reverse(array, n, size-1);
}

// reverse elements in the array[pos_from ... pos_to]
void reverse(int array[], int pos_from, int pos_to)
{
   ...
}
```

Implementing `reverse(int array[], int pos_from, int pos_to)` using swaps is left as an exercise for the reader. Hint: This can be done in linear time.

Comment: @daydreamer You may refer to this document: http://www.cs.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/pearls/s02b.pdf If you swap the 2nd and 3rd reverse in Sanjit's code, it's more easy to understand.

Comment: The link does not work. Can you provide a link with a proof for this method?

Comment: @AryakSengupta, The link can be found on the Internet Archive: https://web.archive.org/web/20080725052919/http://www.cs.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/pearls/s02b.pdf

Answer (score 19):

Let us say we have a function called `arr_reverse(arr,i,j)` which reverses the elements of the array `arr` between index `i` and `j` using the `swap` function.

Example:

```
arr = {1,2,3,4,5} 
i = 0
j = 2
```

then the function will return:

```
{3,2,1,4,5} 
 ^^^^^
```

Implementing this function is straight forward and is `O(N)`.

Now let's use this function in rotating the array.

```
arr     = {1,2,3,4,5} // input array
k       = 2 // amount of right rotation
result  = {4,5,1,2,3} // expected result 
l       = 5 // length of array.

Step 1: Call arr_reverse(arr,l-k,l-1) which is arr_reverse(arr,3,4)
we get {1,2,3,5,4} 
              ^^^

Step 2: Call arr_reverse(arr,0,l-k-1) which is arr_reverse(arr,0,2)
we get {3,2,1,5,4}
        ^^^^^     

Step 3: Call arr_reverse(arr,0,l-1) which is arr_reverse(arr,0,4)
we get {4,5,1,2,3} 
        ^^^^^^^^^
```

The entire process makes use of `arr_reverse` 3 times, making it `O(N)`

Comment: I think you made a typo in Step 2 and 3 of your example, where you show the result. You have the 4 and 5 flipped from what they should be.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a better solution, of a different nature than the others.  It involves fewer array swaps than the others.  Python:

```
import fractions
# rotates an array in-place i positions to the left, in linear time
def rotate(arr,i):
    n = len(arr)
    reps = fractions.gcd(n,i)
    swaps = n / reps
    for start in xrange(reps):
        ix = start
        tmp = arr[ix]
        for s in xrange(swaps-1):
            previx = ix
            ix = (ix + i) % n
            arr[previx] = arr[ix]
        arr[ix] = tmp
    return arr
```

Comment: This ain't linear!

Answer (score 2):

Using linear time O(2N+m), and constant space O(4). m = GCD(n, p)

It's up to 50% faster than the swapping approach, because swapping requires writing O(N) times to a temporary.

http://www.eis.mdx.ac.uk/staffpages/r_bornat/oldteaching/I2A/slides%209%20circshift.pdf

```
for (m=0, count=0; count!=n; m++) {
    type t=A[m];
    for (i=m, j=m+p; j!=m; i=j, j = j+p<n ? j+p : j+p-n, count++)
        A[i]=A[j];
    A[i]=t; count++;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Short Answer (python code)**

```
def reverse(arr, i, j):
    for idx in xrange((j - i + 1) / 2):
        arr[i+idx], arr[j-idx] = arr[j-idx], arr[i+idx]

def solution(A, K):
    l = len(A)
    if l == 0:
        return []
    K = K%l
    reverse(A, l - K, l -1)
    reverse(A, 0, l - K -1)
    reverse(A, 0, l - 1)
    return A
```

**Long Answer (code explanation)**

Let me talk first the base case with `K < N`, the idea in this case is to split the array in two parts `A` and `B`, `A` is the first `N-K` elements array and `B` the last `K` elements. the algorithm reverse `A` and `B` separately and finally reverse the full array (with the two part reversed separately). To manage the case with `K > N`, think that every time you reverse the array `N` times you obtain the original array again so we can just use the module operator to find where to split the array (reversing only the really useful times avoiding useless shifting).

A graphical step by step example can help understanding better the concept. Note that

- The bold line indicate the the splitting point of the array (K = 3 in this example);
- The two red array indicate, respectively, the input and the expected output.

Starting from:

[image: first array]

look that what we want in front of the final output will be the last 3 letter reversed, for now let reverse it in place (first reverse of the algorithm):

[image: second array]

now reverse the first N-K elements (second reverse of the algorithm):

[image: third array]

we already have the solution but in the opposite direction, we can solve it reversing the whole array (third and last reverse of the algorithm):

[image: final array]

Here the final output, the original array cyclical rotated with `K = 3`.

Let give also another step by step example with python code, starting from:

```
A = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
K = 22
N = len(A)
```

we find the splitting index:

```
K = K%N
#2
```

because, in this case, the first 20 shift will be useless, now we reverse the last `K` (2) elements of the original array:

```
reverse(A, N-K, N-1)
# [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 9]
```

as you can see 9 and 10 has been shift, now we reverse the first N-K elements:

```
reverse(A, 0, N-K-1)
# [8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 10, 9]
```

And, finally, we reverse the full array:

```
reverse(A, 0, N-1)
# [9, 10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Note that reversing an array have time complexity O(N).

Answer (score 1):

a naive pseudocode implementation:

```
for (n = 0; n < i; n++) {
    for (j = array.length-1; j > n; j--)
        swap(j, j-1)
}
```

Repeatedly moves the last element to the front, stopping before it moves anything previously moved to the front

Comment: @prp - Might have mentioned that in the question then, eh?

Answer (score 1):

Better use a direct and simple function, complexity N:

```
int rotate(int* a,int DIM,int rn,int* b) {
    int i; //counter 
    for(i=0;i<DIM;i++){ // looping through the array
        b[(i+rn)%len]=a[i]; // copying the values in the b array=a shifted with rn(+ for right or - for left shifting
}
```

Answer (score 1):

using only swap, following is a C++ implementation

```
template<class T>
void rotate_array(std::vector<T> *array, int i) {
  int n = array->size();
  i = i % n;
  int gcd_n_i = gcd(i, n);
  for (int j = 0; j < gcd_n_i; j++) {
    T first_element = array->at(j);
    for (int k = j; (k + i) % n != j; k = (k + i) % n) {
      std::swap(array->at(k), array->at((k + i) % n));
    }
  }
}
```

You can read more about it at http://pointer-overloading.blogspot.in/2013/09/algorithms-rotating-one-dimensional.html

Comment: Upvote for the link; algorith-wise I like the three-reverse method discussed there (and here) better.

Answer (score 1):

```
public int[] shift(int[] A, int K) {
    int N = A.length;
    if (N == 0)
        return A;
    int mid =  -K % N;
    if (mid < 0)
        mid += N;
    if (mid == 0)
        return A;

    reverseSubArray(A, 0 , mid - 1);

    reverseSubArray(A, mid , N - 1);

    reverseSubArray(A, 0 , N - 1);

    return A;
}

private void reverseSubArray(int[] A, int start , int end){
    int i = 0;
    int tmp;
    while (i < (end - start + 1) / 2) {
        tmp = A[i + start];
        A[i + start] = A[end - i];
        A[end - i] = tmp;
        i++;
    }

}
```

[Doug McIlroy’s Handwaving Description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WF9QV.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

This algorithm does (at most) `len(array)-1` swaps, and works with both positive (right) and negative (left) rotation amounts. The array is modified in-place.
It doesn't require calculating the GCD, unlike other similar methods.

(Python 3)

```
def rotate(array,amount):
    if amount<0:
        amount+=len(array)
    a=0
    b=0
    for _ in range(len(array)-1):
        b=(b+amount) % len(array)
        if b==a:
            a+=1
            b=a
        if b!=a:
            array[a],array[b] = array[b],array[a] #swap array[a],array[b]
    return array
```

[image: A diagram drawn in MS Paint]
When one cycle is not enough (if it returns to the start before reaching every index), start a new cycle, from the next index.

Note: rotating items a, b, c, d, ... can be done using
`swap a,b` `swap a,c` `swap a,d` ...

Answer (score 0):

why only swap function?

O(n) in time and space:

```
var rotateCount = 1;
var arr = new Array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);

tmp = new Array(arr.length);
for (var i = 0; i<arr.length; i++)
    tmp[(i+rotateCount)%arr.length]=arr[i];
arr = tmp;

alert(arr);
```

Comment: This code doesn't work. Try rotateCount = 8, it produces: 9,10,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,1.

Comment: Still broken, try rotateCount = 3, it'll produce: 4,5,6,7,8,9,10,2,3,1.

Comment: Also, you really should test your code before posting it. It took me 3 seconds to test this and see that it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package rotateinlineartime;

/**
 *
 * @author Sunshine
 */
public class Rotator {

    void reverse(int a[], int n) {
        for (int i = 0; i <= n - 1; i++) {
            int temp;
            temp = a[i];
            a[i] = a[n - 1];
            a[n - 1] = temp;
            n--;
        }

        printArray(a);
    }

    void printArray(int a[]) {
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(a[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/* Q: How can we shift/rotate an array in place?
A: "in place" means O(1) space complexity, so we need to do some trick
 */

#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

void ArrayRotate(int a[], int n, int k)
{
    if (n < 1 || k % n == 0 ) return;

    k %= n;
    if (k < 0) k += n;

    reverse(a, a+k);
    reverse(a+k, a+n);
    reverse(a, a+n);
}

void PrintArray(int a[], int n)
{
    for ( int i = 0 ; i < n; ++i)
        cout << a[i] << " ";
    cout << endl;
}

int main()
{
    int a[] = { 1, 2 , 3, 4, 5 };
    int n = sizeof(a)/sizeof (a[0]);

    PrintArray(a, n);
    ArrayRotate(a, n, 2);
    PrintArray(a, n);

    return 0;
}
/* Output:
1 2 3 4 5
3 4 5 1 2
 */
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void reverse_array(int a[], int start, int end){

    while(start < end){     
            int temp =  a[start];
            a[start] = a[end];
            a[end] = temp;
            start++;
            end--;
    }
```

}

```
void rotate_array(int a[], int pivot, int len){
    int i;
    /*Reverse the whole array */
    reverse_array(a, 0, len);

    /* Reverse from 0 to pivot and pivot to end */
    reverse_array(a,0, pivot);
    reverse_array(a,pivot+1,len);
```

}

Comment: This is identical to the accepted answer, which also came 3 years earlier. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a small snippet thats works in O(n), written in JavaScript.
The keyconcept is, that you always have to work with the replaced item.

```
function swap(arr, a, v) {
    var old = arr[a];
    arr[a] = v;
    return old;
}

function rotate(arr, n) {
    var length = arr.length;
    n = n % length;
    if(!n) return arr;

    for(var cnt = 0, 
            index = 0,
            value = arr[index],
            startIndex = index; 
        cnt < length; 
        cnt++) {

        // Calc next index
        var nextIndex = mapIndex(index, n, length);

        // Swap value with next
        value = swap(arr, nextIndex, value)

        if(nextIndex == startIndex) {
            startIndex = index = mapIndex(index, 1, length);
            value = arr[index];
        } else {
            index = nextIndex;
        }
    }

    return arr;
}

function mapIndex(index, n, length) {
    return (index - n + length) % length;
}

console.log(rotate([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], 5))
console.log(rotate([1,2,3,4,5,6], 2))
```

Answer (score 0):

An `O(1)` method of accomplishing this, in python:

```
class OffsetList(list):
    __slots__ = 'offset'
    def __init__(self, init=[], offset=-1):
        super(OffsetList, self).__init__(init)
        self.offset = offset
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return super(OffsetList, self).__getitem__(key + self.offset)
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        return super(OffsetList, self).__setitem__(key + self.offset, value)
    def __delitem__(self, key):
        return super(OffsetList, self).__delitem__(key + self.offset)
    def index(self, *args):
        return super(OffsetList, self).index(*args) - self.offset
```

This is based on [this answer about using a 1-based list in python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6714135/1324631).

This does have the slight glitch that if you attempt to index an item off the end of the list, it will return items from the (new) beginning, and negative indicies less than the size minus the offset won't work.

Answer (score 0):

here is my answer using js hope this helps 
where k is the number of the rotations you want to preform

```
 var arrayRoatate=function(array,k){
    for(;k>0;k--) {
     var nextElementValue=undefined;
        for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i=i+2) {
            var nextElement = i + 1;
            if (nextElement >= array.length)
                nextElement = nextElement - array.length;
            var tmp=array[i];
            if(nextElementValue!==undefined)
                array[i]=nextElementValue
            nextElementValue=array[nextElement];
            array[nextElement]=tmp;

        }
    }
return array;
```

Answer (score 0):

> For circular right rotation.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = scan.nextInt();
    int k = scan.nextInt() % n;
    int q = scan.nextInt();
    int arr[] = new int[n];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
    {
        int a = i + k;
        int pos = (a < n) ? a : a - n;
        arr[pos] = scan.nextInt();
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < q; j++) 
    {
        System.out.println(arr[scan.nextInt()]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Here we took the inputs in such a order that the input looks as if it is taken in right rotated manner.

Answer (score 0):

My solution with java

```
static int[] rotLeft(int[] a, int d) {
    for (int i = 0; i < d; i++) {
        oneRotation(a);
    }
    return a;
}

static void oneRotation(int[] a) {
    int firstElement = a[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length - 1; i++) {
        a[i] = a[i + 1];
    }
    a[a.length - 1] = firstElement;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public static String rotateKTimes(String str,int k){
    int n = str.length();

    //java substring has O(n) complexity
    return str.substring(n-k) + str.substring(0,n-k);
}
```

Comment: he asked for integer array to reverse. not `string`

Answer (score -1):

```
Simple Solution in O(n) time and using O(1) space:
for e.g 1,2,3,4,5,6,7
rotating 2 times 
start with index 2, store a[0] as last
Iteration 1: 1,2,1,4,3,6,5 (1-->3-->5-->7)
Iteration 2: 1,7,1,2,3,4,5 (2-->4-->6)
replace 1 with 6 (last value).

public int[] roatateArray(int[] a,int k)
{
    int last = a[0];
    int start = k;
    for(int j=0;j<k;j++) {
    for(int i=start;i<a.length;i+=k)
    {
        int tmp=a[i];
        a[i]=last;
        last=tmp;
    }
    start--;
    if (start<=0) break;
    }
    a[0]=last;
    return a;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
void rotate(int array [], int n, int k)
{
    int temp1,temp2;     //two variable to hold values
    int visited,count,index;   //'visited' to check if cycle 
                               // collides with index
                               //'count' to check number of loops
    visited = n-1;
    temp1 = array[n-1];
    index = n-1;
    count = 0;

    while(count<n)
    {   
        temp2 = temp1;
        temp1 = array[(n+index-k)%n];
        array[(n+index-k)%n] = temp2;
        index = (n+index-k)%n;
        if (index == visited)
        {   
            cout<<"\nindex == visited at index = "<<index;
            getch();
            index--;
            visited=index;
            temp1=array[index];
        }
        count++;
        cout<<"\ncount is : "<<count;
        cout<<"\narray is : ";
        p_all_arr(array,0,n); //display arr 
        getch();
    }

}
```