# Rotation of the array means that each element is shifted right by one index, and the last element of the array is also moved to the first place

Tags: java, arrays

For example, the rotation of `array A = [3, 8, 9, 7, 6] is [6, 3, 8, 9, 7]`. The goal is to rotate array A K times;
that is, each element of A will be shifted to the right by K indexes.

For example, given array `A = [3, 8, 9, 7, 6]` and `K = 3`, the function should return `[9, 7, 6, 3, 8]`.

I want this in java.
I have tried this.

```
public static int[] rotation(int[] a,int k) {

    int[] newArray = new int[a.length];
    for(int i = 0 ; i < a.length ; i++) {
        int newPosition = (i + k)%a.length;
        newArray[newPosition] = a[i];
    }
    return newArray;
}
```

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4457277/algorithm-to-rotate-an-array-in-linear-time

Comment: What is the problem? What do you expect and what actually happens?

Comment: now how to print it?

Comment: please write the program

Comment: This is working! Please do some test first and some research on how to print an array in console.

Comment: Try `Arrays.stream(resultArray).forEach(System.out::println);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use `A = B.clone();`

```
public int[] solution(int[] A, int K) {
    // write your code in Java SE 8

    int [] B =new int [A.length];

    for(int l=0;K>l;K--){
        int j=0;
        for(int i=0;i<A.length;i++){
            if(i==0){
                B[j]=A[A.length-1];
                j++;
            }
            else{
                B[j]=A[i-1];
                j++;
            }
        }

        //below part
        /*for(int i= 0;i<A.length;i++){
            A[i]=B[i];
        }*/
        A = B.clone();

    }
    return B;
}
```

If you like :D

Answer (score 5):

I didnt get what exactly wants topic starter but here my code for this task

```
class Solution {
public int[] solution(int[] arr, int k) {
    int[] newArr = new int[arr.length];

    if (arr.length == 0) return arr;
       k = k%arr.length;
    for (int i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {

      newArr[i] = arr[(i + (arr.length - k)) % (arr.length)];

    }

    return newArr;
}
```

}

Comment: Great solution!

Answer (score 1):

You can print the result using `Arrays.toString`. For example:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(rotation(new int[] { 3, 8, 9, 7, 6}, 3)));
```

Comment: you can make a comment for such small thing.

Comment: It answers the question as explained in comment of Dhaval Mistry. A small question gets a small answer. I added an example.

Answer (score 1):

**Achieved 100% correctness**

```
public int[] solution(int[] A, int K) {
    // write your code in Java SE 8
    if(K == A.length || A.length == 0)
        return A;
    if(K > A.length) {
        K = K%A.length;
    }
    int[] arr1 = Arrays.copyOfRange(A, A.length-K, A.length);
    int[] arr2 = Arrays.copyOfRange(A, 0, A.length-K);
    int aLen = arr1.length;
    int bLen = arr2.length;
    int[] result = new int[aLen + bLen];
    System.arraycopy(arr1, 0, result, 0, aLen);
    System.arraycopy(arr2, 0, result, aLen, bLen);
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public int[] solution(int[] A, int K) {
    // write your code in Java SE 8

    int [] B =new int [A.length];

    for(int l=0;K>l;K--){
        int j=0;
        for(int i=0;i<A.length;i++){
            if(i==0){
                B[j]=A[A.length-1];
                j++;
            }
            else{
                B[j]=A[i-1];
                j++;
            }
        }
        for(int i= 0;i<A.length;i++){
            A[i]=B[i];
        }

    }
    return B;
}
```

Comment: Please add some description to explain answer for benefit of other.

Answer (score 0):

```
  function solution(A, K) {

        function shiftArray(arrayToShift, newArray=[] ){
            newArray[0] = arrayToShift[arrayToShift.length-1] ; 
            for (var i=1; i<arrayToShift.length; i++){
                newArray[i] = arrayToShift[i-1];   
            }
            // console.log("arrayToShift");
            // console.log(newArray);
            return newArray;
        }


        var newArray = A;
        for(var i=0; i<K; i++){
            newArray =  shiftArray(newArray);
        }
        return newArray
    }


console.log(solution([3, 8, 9, 7, 6], 3));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution using JavaScript, **tested 100%.**

```
function solution(A, K) {
    for(let i=0; i<K; i++) {
        let lastIndex = A.length - 1;
        let lastItem = A[lastIndex];
        for(let j=(A.length-1); j>-1; j--) {
            if(j>0) {
                A[j] = A[j-1];
            } else {
                A[j] = lastItem;
            }
        }
    }
    return A;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

class Solution { 
    public int[] solution(int[] A, int K){

```
    if((A.length == 0) || (K == 0)){
        return A;
    }
    int [] B = new int[A.length];
    int c = K;
    while(c != 0){
        for(int i = 1; i< A.length; i++){
            B[i] = A[i-1];
        }
        c--;
        B[0] = A[A.length-1];
        System.arraycopy(B, 0, A, 0, A.length);
    }
    return A;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

In Kotlin:

```
fun flipList(list: List<Int>, times: Int): List<Int> {
    val flippedList = list.toMutableList()
    val referenceList = list.toMutableList()
    repeat(times) {
        var position = 0
        referenceList.forEach {
            position++
            if (position < list.size)
                flippedList[position] = referenceList[position -1]
            else
                flippedList[0] = referenceList.last()
        }
        referenceList.clear()
        referenceList.addAll(flippedList)
    }
    return flippedList
}
```

Unit Teste

```
class FlipListUnitTest {
        private val referenceListMock = listOf(1,2,3,4)
        private val referenceListOneTimeFlipResultMock = listOf(4,1,2,3)
        private val referenceListFourTimesFlipResultMock = listOf(1,2,3,4)
        @Test
        fun `check test api is working`(){
            assertTrue(true)
        }

        @Test
        fun `check list flip 1 time`(){
            assertTrue(flipList(referenceListMock, 1) == referenceListOneTimeFlipResultMock)
        }

        @Test
        fun `check list flip 4 time`(){
            assertTrue(flipList(referenceListMock, 4) == referenceListFourTimesFlipResultMock)
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here in my code

```
public static int[] solution(int[] A, int K){
    if(A.length > 0) {
        for(int i = 0; i < K ; i++){
            int temp = A[A.length - 1];
            for(int j = A.length - 2; j >= 0; j--){
                A[j + 1] = A[j];
            }
            A[0] = temp;
        }
    }
    return A;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int[] solution(int[] A, int K) {
    if(A.length<1)
        return A;
    int[] newArray = new int[A.length];

    while (K>0){
        newArray[0]=A[A.length-1];
        for(int i=0; i<A.length-1; i++){
            newArray[i+1]=A[i];
        }
        for (int i=0; i<newArray.length; i++) {
            A[i]=newArray[i];
        }
        K--;
    }
    return A;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> An array A consisting of N integers is given. Rotation of the array means that each element is shifted right by one index, and the last element of the array is moved to the first place.

Hi everyone here is another simple solution for this problem in JAVA, 100% working.

```
class Solution {
    public int[] solution(int[] A, int K) {
        
        // Corner cases to save resources
         if(K == 0 || A.length <= 0 || A.length == K){
             return A;
         }
         
         // Loop to traverse K times
         for(int i=0; i<K; i++){
             int last = A[A.length - 1]; // Last digit
             
             // Loop to traverse A.Length times in swing order,
             // so that first element can be set
             for(int j=A.length-1; j>0; j--){
              A[j] = A[j-1];   
             }
             
             // Set last element
             A[0] = last;
         }
         
         // Return result
         return A;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer in JavaScript

```js
function solution(A, K){
let arr = [];
let lastIndex = A.length -1;
        let rotation = K-1;
    for(let i = 0; i < K; i++){
        arr[rotation] = A[lastIndex];
        --lastIndex; 
        --rotation;
    }

    for(let j = 0; j <= lastIndex; j++){
        arr.push(A[j]);
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer in Python without loop and using string substitution

```
def solution(A, K):
    K = K % len(A) if K > len(A) else K
    if (K == 0) or (K == len(A)) or (len(A) in [0, 1]):
        return A
    
    first_index = len(A) - K
    return A[first_index:] + A[:first_index]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function solution(A, K) {
   let tmpA = [];
   for (let i = 1; i <= K; i++){
       tmpA.unshift(A.pop());
   }
   for (let i = 1; i <= K; i++){
       A.unshift(tmpA.pop());
   }
   return A;   
}
```

Comment: This answer appears to be Javascript code.  The question requested Java code and gave an attempt in Java, not Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code written in PHP but logic can be used in any language.

```
function solution($A, $K) {
// write your code in PHP7.0      
    $cnt = count($A);
    for($i=1; $i<=$K; $i++){ 
        foreach($A as $key=>$val){
            $key++;
            if($key==$cnt){
                $A[0] = $val;
            }
            else
            {   
                $A[$key] = $val;
            }
        }
    }
    return $A;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int[] rotateArrayKTimes(int[] A, int K) {

        if (A.length == 0 || A.length > 1000 || K > 100) {
            return new int[]{};
        }
        for (int index = 0; index < K; index++) {
            int temp = A[A.length - 1];
            System.arraycopy(A, 0, A, 1, A.length - 1);
            A[0] = temp;
        }
        return A;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

javascript | score: 100%

function solution(A, K) {

```
for(let i=0 ; i<K ; i++){
    let lastIndex = A.length-1;
    let lastNumber = A[lastIndex];
    A.unshift(lastNumber);
    A.pop();
}
return A;
```

}

Comment: Your post is mostly code, please add some more explanation of how it works

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

JAVA solution -

```
class Solution2 {
    public int[] solution(int[] arr, int k) {
        int temp;
        int startindex = 0;
        if (arr.length != 0) {
            for (int i = 1; i <= k; i++) {
                temp = arr[arr.length - 1];
                for (int j = arr.length - 1; j >= startindex; j--) {

                    if (j != (startindex)) {
                        arr[j] = arr[j - 1];
                    } else
                        arr[startindex] = temp;
                }
            }
        } else
            System.out.println("This is empty array");
        return arr;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is my simple solution in Python.
I guess it works:

```
def funcRotation(A,z):
    
    B = [0] * len(A)

    for r in range(1,z+1):
    
        for a in range(len(A)):
            #print("a = ",a,"r = ",r)

            B[a] = A[a-r]
            #print(B)

    return B

funcRotation([1,2,3,4],4)
```

Comment: Pardon me, but how does Python code help someone who is asking for Java code? Also, what do you mean by: _I guess it works_ ?