# Right shift elements in an array by n

Tags: c#, arrays, algorithm

I want to shift elements in one array to right by **only changing the index**. Also **I don't want to use built-in functions**

For example, if we have

> 8,6,5,3,9

Then We will have

> 9,8,6,5,3

If the array doesn't have enough length. the rest of the elements shift will start from the first index of array.

```
   int index = 0, temp = 0;
        int[] myarray = new int[int.Parse(Console.ReadLine())];
        for (int i = 0; i < myarray.Length; i++)
        {
            myarray[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < myarray.Length; i++)
        {
            if (myarray.Length <= i + 5)
            {
                index = ((i + 5) % 5);
                temp = myarray[index];
                myarray[index] = myarray[i];
                myarray[i] = temp;
            }
            else
            {
                temp = myarray[i + 5];
                myarray[i + 5] = myarray[i];
                myarray[i] = temp;
            }
        }
```

this is what i have tried but its not working

Comment: It would be nice if you describe your algorithm and elaborate on *"it's not working"*. Few comments in source may suffice.

Comment: Your example is one shift right.

Comment: @Guy If the array doesn't have enough length. the rest of the elements shift will start from the first index of an array.For example six shift 2 from last and 3 from first.

Comment: @Sherviniv yes, this is how it works. But shift by 5 will leave an array with size 5 the same.

Comment: @Sinatr I filled my array in first for.Then i tried to change index with secound for.if the next index + 5 was more than the length of the array do something.I dont have no idea to how implement it.

Comment: @Guy So this is the hard point I don't want to use another array to keep old values. but if you know a way with temp variable its ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If shift count is less than or equal array size you can use this code (I edited answer by [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/876410/11617122)):

```
        using System;

        int M = 5;//shift count
        int size; //size of array
        int[] myarray = new int[int.Parse(Console.ReadLine())];
        for (int i = 0; i < myarray.Length; i++)
        {
            myarray[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        }

        size = myarray.Length;
        if (size >= M)
        {
            Array.Reverse(myarray, 0, size);
            Array.Reverse(myarray, 0, M);
            Array.Reverse(myarray, M, size - M);

            for (int i = 0; i < myarray.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.Write(myarray[i]+"\t");
            }

            Console.Read();
         }
```

Comment: It is not working, if i enter 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8,1 must be as same place as 6,it must shift to right by 5

Comment: I think you can use this answer:  [Fastest algorithm for circle shift N sized array for M position](https://stackoverflow.com/a/876410/11617122)

Comment: Thanks for your Answer,Could you explain more about each reverse.

Comment: @Sherviniv the description of algorithm is in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/876410/11617122) post.