# list pop and insert are very slow in python

Tags: python, list

I am working on a leetcode question 189. Rotate Array.

Problem statement:
Given an array, rotate the array to the right by k steps, where k is non-negative.
Input: nums = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7], k = 3
Output: [5,6,7,1,2,3,4]

Following is my code. My understanding is that the time complexity is O(k), but it ends up being very low. Could you please shine some light on this and educate me?

```
class Solution:
    def rotate(self, nums: List[int], k: int) -> None:
        """
        Do not return anything, modify nums in-place instead.
        """
        while k:
            nums.insert(0,nums.pop())
            k -= 1
```

Comment: You might want to consider a different approach that doesn't modify the array on each step, but think about how you could reindex the array to be shifted like that.

Comment: What do you mean by very slow? there isn't a lot here to cause real performance issues

Comment: Either way - lists in CPython are implemented as simple arrays of pointers, so a pop is simple, but an insert at 0 requires shifting everything to the right and setting the first entry.

Comment: List is not ideal for this `insert(0)` (to the head) ops.  Better to think other way for handling bigger list.

Comment: @Sayse, my code took 3144 ms, other solutions take about 100 ms.

Comment: Of course, `.insert(0, x)` is *linear time*. So your algorithm will be O(K*N), where `K` is the magnitude of `k`, and N is the length of `nums`. i.e. it's polynomial time, when it can be done in linear time

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, really? .insert(0,x) takes O(n) time??

Comment: @AlbertGLieu *of course*. How could it not? But yeah, this is a fundamental performance characteristic here.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, I don't understand how python implemented list, originally I thought it used a linked list kind of thing, think insert and pop only take O(1). I need to look up to make sure. But I am very likely to be wrong. Thank you very much.

Comment: @AlbertGLieu no, absolutely not. A linked list would be *disasterous* for typical use-cases, it is implemented as an Array List, this is why access is constant time, i.e. `mylist[0]` takes the same time as `mylist[10_000]` Typically, the only places you'd see a linked list as a default implementation is in a functional programming language, i.e. a "cons list".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fastest algorithm for circle shift N sized array for M position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/876293/fastest-algorithm-for-circle-shift-n-sized-array-for-m-position)

Comment: @AlbertGLieu https://stackoverflow.com/questions/876293/fastest-algorithm-for-circle-shift-n-sized-array-for-m-position/32698823#32698823 if you want to have better approach and solve the problem as it is asked ( basically idea is circular shift )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach is to use a deque [`rotate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque.rotate), as below

```
from collections import deque
from typing import List

class Solution:
    def rotate(self, nums: List[int], k: int) -> None:
        """
        Do not return anything, modify nums in-place instead.
        """
        dnums = deque(nums)
        dnums.rotate(k)
        nums[:] = dnums


nums = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
Solution().rotate(nums, 3)
print(nums)
```

**Output**

```
[5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

From the documentation (emphasis mine):

> Rotate the deque n steps to the right.    If n is negative, rotate to
> the left.    When the deque is not empty, rotating one step to the
> right is    equivalent to **d.appendleft(d.pop())**, and rotating one
> step to the left is equivalent to d.append(d.popleft()).

The problem with inserting at the beginning of a list is that it is O(n), you have to shift all the elements. In a deque inserting at the beginning (appendleft) is O(1).

For more details about the time complexity of deque and list, see [`here`](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity)

Comment: That's one option, but I'm pretty sure there's a simple `nums[:] = [nums[(i + shift % ...` sort of approach to this too :-)

Comment: thanks Dani for the solution, I mainly want to understand why my code is so slow compared to others. Do you happen to know why.

Comment: But that's no faster than the pop/append solution.

Comment: @TimRoberts why do you say?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga The computational requirements are the same  Allocate memory, copy the elements, add the new one.  One is implicit, one is explicit, but the time should be the same.

Comment: @TimRoberts no, no it isn't. The problem is that in the OP's solution, you copy the entire underlying buffer *for each of the k iterations*. In the above, the copy is done once, up front, then the re-arranging is handled by an efficient, internal algorithim that is only O(K), so this algorith will only be O(N), whereas the OP's will be O(N*K). EDIT: perhaps what's missing is that deque is implemented a a linked list (sorta, actually, it's more of a "rope", since it's a doubly-linked list of array blocks)

Comment: @TimRoberts a form of this question is asked earlier in SO [fastest curclar shift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/876293/fastest-algorithm-for-circle-shift-n-sized-array-for-m-position/), which was also given as a hint in question in leetcode

Comment: You're right, I overlooked the "one at a time" vs "many at a time" difference in my quick glance.

Answer (score 2):

`Deque` is great DS for this. Alternatively, you can try this:
This got accepted and ranked 88% in Python category. (about the same speed as `deque`)

[Note] the length of list is 10^5.  It asks for `in-place` ops.

```
 def rotate(self, nums: List[int], k: int) -> None:
     """
     Do not return anything, modify nums in-place instead.
     """
     z = len(nums)
     k = k % z
        
     nums[:] = nums[z-k:] +nums[:z-k]
```

Comment: Simple and pythonic. This is very informative.

Answer (score 0):

FYI, in the case you use `numpy`

```
import numpy as np

nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
k = 3

print(np.roll(nums, k).tolist())

# Output:
[5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: sadly using numpy is not recommended in Leetcode